# EventHubProducerClient unit testing in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-eventhub

I find that EventHubProducerClient is not unit test friendly (not mockable) in c# and how do you go about testing it, like `SendEventsAsync` method?

Answer (score 6):

Support for mocking and unit testing is one of the core goals of the new Azure SDKs, and the details of the approach that we use is discussed in the [Azure SDK Design Guidelines](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/dotnet_introduction.html#dotnet-mocking).  All of the public members of `EventHubProducerClient` are `virtual` or settable, the class is not sealed, and a parameterless constructor is available to ensure that it is usable with a mocking library such as Moq or FakeItEasy.

You should be able to mock the client using the same approach that you prefer for other types, either by using a mocking framework or inheriting from the class and creating your own mock type.

I'd like to understand a bit more about your statement that the client could not be mocked or tested effectively.  Was there a specific scenario or difficulty that you were running into that we may be able to help with?

Comment: My application does create a EventDataBatch and send them. I see that I can mock `EventHubProducerClient` class but how to I mock the below statement i when EventDataBatch is sealed class.

EventDataBatch eventBatch = await eventHubProducerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

Comment: Each of the Azure SDKs has a model factory class that allows creation of the types returned from service operations that can't normally be directly created.   In this case, you can use the [EventHubsModelFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubsmodelfactory) to create a batch intended for mocking.  The structures returned from query Event Hubs runtime properties are also available via the factory.

Comment: One of the most important cross-cutting features of our new client libraries using Azure.Core is that they are designed for mocking. 

Take a look at 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/README.md#mocking

Comment: @JesseSquire not seeing how that helps much, if i have code that creates a batch and sends that to ProducerClient how can i verify which messages made it to which batch, all the pieces of EventDataBatch that let you read the events are internal

Comment: When you create the batch via the model factory, it uses a list that you supply as backing store.  You're free to inspect it that list.  The events it contains are those in the batch.   See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubsmodelfactory.eventdatabatch?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-eventhubs-eventhubsmodelfactory-eventdatabatch(system-int64-system-collections-generic-ilist((azure-messaging-eventhubs-eventdata))-azure-messaging-eventhubs-producer-createbatchoptions-system-func((azure-messaging-eventhubs-eventdata-system-boolean)))

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own interface with `SendEventsAsync` and use it in your classes, which will allow you to easily mock it in unit tests.

Comment: Adding your own interface with `SendEventsAsync` may work fine but the `CreateBatchAsync()` method returns a `sealed EventDataBatch` class. I don't see how one mocks that as you can't create an instance or inherit from that class. Jesse below indicates the EventHubsModelFactory to solve this.